# Routing requests from S3 static website to EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, angular5

I have a problem that I cant POST/GET from my website to my backend API.
Front-end which is implemented with angular 5 is held in Amazon S3 bucket as a static website. How can you make your angular 5 front-end interact with API that is hosted in EC2 instance? Both applications are working but not interacting to change information.
So how can you POST/GET data from Amazon S3 to EC2 instance based backend?

Comment: What's the issue you're seeing? Is it a network timeout? Is your service running on the EC2 instance and accessible the IP you're trying to hit it from?

Comment: The issue I am seeing  is that the front-end application says that connection is refused although my node backend has been configured to CORS from the angular 5 front-end that is located in amazon s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure you are thinking about this the right way. A client downloads your static web content from S3. So a better way of thinking about this is that your user has your website on their host. S3 can't connect to anything because it doesn't run code.

In order to connect your client to your backend API, you will need some client side code, which probably means using javascript. Angular has modules available to help with this, trying looking up the HttpClient service. You should also check whether the API you wish to connect to has any SDKs available.

Comment: well the angular application has the code for connecting and interacting with API. Just that every request says that connection is refused. Everything was working when the front-end application was held in the same EC2 instance but for some reasons decided to transfer the front-end application to S3 bucket. Now the requests are not working although the API specific urls are changed and configured

Comment: OK, sounds like we need more details on your backend server. Has anyone connected to your API service remotely before or is this the first time? The obvious problem would be that the routing to your server isn't working.

Comment: When I use Postman for testing the API endpoints everything is fine and okay, but when the request is initiated in the front-end application that is stored in S3, it seems to me that the request does not reach the endpoint or is refused

Comment: That's good. There must be some misconfiguration in the application. You will need to do some debugging so that you can compare the Postman request with the request coming from the application. You could use Wireshark, or just have your application write the request to your log.

Comment: By the way, I assume you mean Postman is deployed on your local machine and not on the EC2 instance?